# Re-publish gradle artifacts

Tags: groovy, gradle, ivy

We have an ivy repository, and we are using gradle for our dependency management and build framework. When an artifact is determined to be production-ready, we don't want to have to build it again, so we want to just "promote" an existing artifact via a web application that is leveraging Gradle and the tooling API to do most of the heaving lifting for us.

Currently, I'm copying the artifacts to a local folder and running another build.gradle that just re-publishes it. We are publishing it to a new folder in our existing repository, and a folder in the release repository.

In doing so, it is only publishing the ivy.xml to both locations.

I'm guessing this is due to where the artifacts are located.

**PromotionService.groovy**

```
void promote(Project project, Build build, String newVersion) {
    def artifactLocation = "/path/to/repository"
    // we are generating this build.gradle and copying it
    def buildFileText = new File('promote.gradle').getText('UTF-8')
    def artifacts = buildDao.findArtifactsByBuild(build)
    def localBuildFolderPath = "/path/to/local/gradle/build"
    def localBuildFolder = new File(localBuildFolderPath)
    localBuildFolder.mkdirs()
    // remove everything currently in the directory
    def buildFiles = localBuildFolder.listFiles()
    buildFiles.each {
        it.delete()
    }
    def newFile = new File("/path/to/local/gradle/build.gradle")
    newFile.mkdirs()
    if (newFile.exists())
        newFile.delete()
    newFile << buildFileText
    artifacts.each { VersionedArtifact it ->
        def folder = new File("${artifactLocation}/${it.module}/${build.branch}/${it.version}")
        def files = folder.listFiles()
        files.each { File from ->
            // remove version number from file name
            String fromName = from.name
            def matcher = fromName =~ /(.*?)-(\d)+\.(\d)+\.(\d)+(\.\d+)?\.(.*)/
            fromName = "${matcher[0][1]}.${matcher[0][6]}"
            File to = new File("${localBuildFolderPath}/${it.module}/${fromName}")
            to.mkdirs()
            if (to.exists()) to.delete()
            // wrapper for Guava's Files.copy()
            FileUtil.copy(from, to)
        }

        ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector().forProjectDirectory(new File("${workingDir}/gradle")).connect()
        connection.newBuild()
            .forTasks("publishReleaseBranchPublicationToIvyRepository", "publishReleaseRepoPublicationToReleaseRepository")
            .withArguments("-PMODULE=${it.module}", "-PVERSION=${it.version}", "-PNEWVERSION=${newVersion}")
            .run()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

publishing {
  publications {
    releaseBranch(IvyPublication) {
        organisation 'our-organization'
        module MODULE
        revision VERSION
        descriptor.status = 'release'

        configurations { archive {
            } }
    }
    releaseRepo(IvyPublication) {
        organisation 'our-organization'
        module MODULE
        revision NEWVERSION
        descriptor.status = 'release'

        configurations { archive {
        }}
    }
}
repositories {
    ivy {
        name 'ivy'
        url "/path/to/ivy/repo"
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy "[organisation]/[module]/release/[revision]/[module]-[revision].xml"
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/release/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]"
        }
    }
    ivy {
        name 'release'
        url "/path/to/release/repo"
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].xml"
            artifact "[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision].[ext]"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Made it clearer we're writing a web application to promote artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why the promotion is implemented using the tooling API, rather than as a regular Gradle task or plugin. Anyway, the `IvyPublication`s are neither configured using `IvyPublication#from`, nor using `IvyPublication#artifact`. Hence they won't have any artifacts.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I've iterated on this a little since I wrote the question (just added from components.java), and it's publishing the artifacts (I'll edit it later on). I wanted to just write a task, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to republish the artifacts, modify the ivy status to release, and maintain all the dependencies.

Comment: It's worth mentioning now, as I realized it was pretty integral to mention that we are building a web application that takes advantage of the tooling API to run Gradle tasks. This application handles the promotion, but we wanted to leverage Gradle to do most of the heavy lifting for us.